# Date validation - Go to next input field once number of characters entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is someone else's code and I am quite new to JS so finding it quite difficult to understand.

I'm trying to auto tab to the next input once the maximum limit has been reached.

The problem I'm having is that the input for year is tabbing before the full year has been fully entered.

If someone could point me to the right direction that would be of great help.

**JS Bin:
https://jsbin.com/wazarezufi/edit?js,output**

```
"use strict";

var parts = el.find('input');

 function constructor(el) {
    console.log('running');

    $('input').on('keyup', _.bind(onKeyup, this))
        .on('keypress', _.bind(onKeypress, this))
        .on('focus', focus)
        .on('paste', _.bind(paste, this));
}

function paste(evt) {
    // allows pasting of dates in
    var str = evt.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'),
        bits;
    if (str && (bits = /(\d\d)[\/\\.-]?(\d\d)[\/\\.-]?(\d\d\d\d)/.exec(str))) {
        parts.each(function (idx) {
            $(this).val(bits[idx + 1]);
        })
        return false;
    }
}

function onKeypressDef(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    var val;
    // find the target in our list
    for (var idx = 0; idx < parts.length; idx++) {
        if (parts[idx] === el) break;
    }
    if ((val = $(el).val()).length == 2) {

        if (idx < parts.length - 1) {
            parts[idx + 1].select();
        }
    }

}

function focus() {
    $(this.select());
};

function onKeyup(e) { // needed to trap the backspace
    console.log('keyup');
    if (e.which === 8) {
        onKeypress.call(this, e);
    }
}

function onKeypress(e) {
    var self = this;
    var evt = e;
    if ((evt.which > 32) && (/\D/.test(String.fromCharCode(evt.which)))) return false; // only let numeric chars through
    _.defer(function () {
        onKeypressDef.call(self, evt);
    });
}
 constructor();
```

Thanks

Comment: You should start with this line: `if ((val = $(el).val()).length == 2) {` which checks if the length of the input equals 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a data attribute where you could specify the length of the input, like so:

```
<input placeholder="YYYY" data-length="4">
```

Then update you javascript to check for this attribute and if not found, then use 2 as the default.

```
if ((val = $_el.val()).length == ($_el.data('length') || 2)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is doing this for any input:

```
if ((val = $(el).val()).length == 2)
```

You should check (by id, for example) which input triggered the event and compare the length to 2 or 4 depending in the case.

Answer (score 0):

Have updated the fiddle -- https://jsbin.com/vojojufabe/edit?js,output
The issue was that the length was being checked when the data is entered and when lenght is 2 it jumps to next input, have added isyear data attribute, and checked it for lenght to be of 4 characters

```
if (!isYear && val=== 2) {

    if (idx < parts.length - 1) {
        parts[idx + 1].select();
    }
}
if (isYear && val=== 4) {

    if (idx < parts.length - 1) {
        parts[idx + 1].select();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adjusting your input length check with something as follows:

```
var l = 2
if (el.id === 'input__date-year-arriveInUk') {
  l = 4
}
if ((val = $(el).val()).length == l) {...
```

You can check whether the id of the current input is the one of your date input and focus the next input after a String of length 4 is entered.